# Signification of "/" in ip address

Tags: ip, nmap

I am learning nmap and I amm watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNThhluanlg at minute 2:30 the speaker does a simple ping scan but wants to perform it on the "whole network" 
for this purpose she uses her ip address but adds a "/" at the end and some numbers...

What do ip addresses with "/" stand for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to understand that an IP address has 32 bits.

Next, you need to understand that a "network" involves machines that are specifically numbered to keep them together.  If you have (say) 11 computers that are going to be together in a network, then their IP addresses will all have their "left" side in common:

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx0001
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx0010
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx0011
...
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx1101
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx1110
```

The number after the slash indicates the number of bits that the machines all have in common.  In this case, whatever value the (reserved) first IP address

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx0000
```

has, the network is identified as  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/28

Comment: Just for completeness, in networking jargon the number after the slash is the bitlength of the subnet mask.

Comment: I spend too much time in "explain like i'm 5".  I need to remember that, when I'm here, I can use actual technical terms. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) (CIDR) notation. The number after the slash says how many bits of the address belong to the routing prefix for the network or subnet. However many bits are left over may be allocated to hosts on that subnet.

As an example, say you are given the address "192.0.2.0/24". An IPv4 address consists of 4 octets, or 32 bits. The notation says that the first 24 bits (3 octets) denote the network, and the remaining 32 - 24 = 8 bits (1 octet) can be used for host addresses. This network can hold 2^8 = 256 hosts, though practically the all-ones address will be used for broadcast and the all-zeros address for the network itself. Therefore, "192.0.2.0/24" is equivalent to "192.0.2.0-255" in Nmap's range syntax, or all addresses between 192.0.2.0 and 192.0.2.255 inclusive.